# Is align the right environment here?

Tags: spacing, formatting, align

I have lots of problems with the following. I want this:
[image]

That's my current code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\lbrace \rho : G \rightarrow \text{GL}(K^n) \, |\, \rho &\, \text{is a homomorphism} \rbrace 
\overset{1:1}\longleftrightarrow
\lbrace \rho':G\rightarrow \text{GL}_n(K) \, | \, \rho' \, \text{is a homomorphism} \rbrace \\
 \rho&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 
 \,\,\, \longmapsto \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?)\circ p \\
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?&)^{-1} \circ \rho'  
 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \longmapsfrom \,\,\, 
 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, 
 \rho'
 \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

I had two put manually space between the mapping of elements. Is there a more elegant solution? Maybe using more ,,&'' signs to say ,,set the first one here, the second one here, and so on...'' Maybe another environment than align is necessary?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no need to ask if there is a more elegant solution than `,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\` better to ask if there is a less elegant one:-), you should avoid space commands as far as possible, and there is never need to have consecutive spaces. If you really needed this you could use `\mskip{20\thinmuskip}` or however many you have.

Comment: Hey David, thank you, you are right!

Comment: Maybe now? My document is huuugeee, so I thought these usepackages are enough for all the commands that I used here

Comment: Yes thanks it is fine now, it really helps a lot if you can simply copy the posted code and run it to see whatever problem is being asked about, and to test answers.

Comment: Yeah thought so after your comment. Honestly I thought you guys can see every problem and solution immediately just by taking a brief look on the code xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd avoid long textual set descriptions. Everybody understands “hom”, in my opinion. The symbol at the left of `\longmapsto` is understood to be a variable in the set above it and similarly for the symbol at the right of `\longmapsfrom`.

I propose two different alignments, take your pick.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools, amsthm,array}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{geometry}

\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ c >{{}}c<{{}} c }
\hom(G,\GL(K^n)) & \overset{1:1}\longleftrightarrow  & \hom(G,\GL_n(K)) \\
\rho             & \longmapsto                       & \mathbf{c}_{B,B}(?)\circ \rho \\
\mathbf{c}_{B,B}(?)^{-1} \circ \rho' & \longmapsfrom &  \rho'
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
\hom(G,\GL(K^n)) & \overset{1:1}\longleftrightarrow  & \hom(G,\GL_n(K)) \\
\rho             & \longmapsto                       & \mathbf{c}_{B,B}(?)\circ \rho \\
\mathbf{c}_{B,B}(?)^{-1} \circ \rho' & \longmapsfrom &  \rho'
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The (local) redefinition of `\arraystretch` is meant to spread out the rows of the array (it's the same as what `amsmath` does for `cases`, for instance).

Why `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}`? We want to rely on the automatic spacing added by TeX in math formulas, instead of padding the columns. So the middle column is set in a special way by means of

```
>{{}}c<{{}}
```

which means that `array` will see `{}\longmapsto{}` or similar in the middle column (see the documentation of the `array` package for the syntax). Since `array` typesets each cell in math mode, the two empty groups provide “phantom atoms” around the relation symbol and TeX will duly insert the standard spacing between these atoms and the relation symbol.

Why `equation*`? Because there is a single object in the display, namely the `array`. It's best to reserve `align` for displays with multiple objects in different rows, hence with `\\` at the “outer level”.

Comment: HEy egreg, the first one is very nice (and you are absolutely right that hom is much better). Could you please explain the commands that you used in the first solution?                  
Why equation* and not align*?
What does \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2} do?
What does \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt} do?
What das c >{{}}c<{{}} c  do?

Comment: @ZPlaya7 I added some explanations

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `tikz-cd` is worth a try here.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1ex]
\lbrace \rho : G \rightarrow \text{GL}(K^n)  \mid \rho  \text{ is a homomorphism} \rbrace 
\arrow[r,"1:1"]&
\lbrace \rho':G\rightarrow \text{GL}_n(K)  \mid  \rho'  
\text{ is a homomorphism} \rbrace 
\\
\rho\arrow[r,mapsto]&
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?)\circ p \\
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?)^{-1} \circ \rho'  
 &\arrow[l,mapsto] \rho'
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm these arrows are way to big :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd use array if you want centred (and `\mid`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{70pt}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{array}{c@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}c}
\lbrace \rho : G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(K^n)  \mid \rho  \text{ is a homomorphism} \rbrace 
&\overset{1:1}\longleftrightarrow&
\lbrace \rho':G\rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_n(K)  \mid  \rho'  \text{ is a homomorphism} \rbrace \\
 \rho
  &\longrightarrow& % to not defined
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?)\circ p \\
 \textbf{c}_{B,B}(?)^{-1} \circ \rho'  
  &\longrightarrow  &% from not defined
   \rho'  
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```